# store google form responses in existing sheet of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-docs, google-forms

I know you can create a form, and send its responses into a new sheet of a Google spreadsheet.

Wondering if it is possible to store form responses in an *existing* sheet of a spreadsheet.

[This page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2917686?hl=en) seems to indicate not, which seems unnecessary.

The form will be embedded in a Wordpress website.

Comment: Can you breifly explain what do you exactly mean...sorry this seems to be too little....

Comment: Not sure what I can add.  Google Docs allows you to create Google Apps forms, which talk to Google Apps spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a Google Form, you are allowed to choose a response destination. It can be a new Spreadsheet or an Existing Spreadsheet, however, you do not get the liberty to choose a specific SHEET, if you know what I mean.

As a workaround, you can use arrayformula to populate the responses from the Form Response Sheet to any sheet you want.